# Enumerating group actions with constrained images, up to symmetries

Tags: co.combinatorics, group-actions, enumerative-combinatorics

Consider the following combinatorial problem:

> Let $G$ be a finite group, and $X = \sqcup_{i\in I} X_i$ be a finite set.
> Suppose that for each $g\in G$ and $i\in I$ we have sets $Y_{g,i} \subset X$, which are each unions of some of the $X_i$.
>
> Define a *constrained action* $\rho$ of $G$ on $X$ to be an action $\rho: G \to \operatorname{Aut}(X)$ such that $\rho(g)(x) \in Y_{g,i}$ for every $g \in G$ and $x \in X_i$.
>
> The permutations $\prod_i S_{X_i}$ act on such constrained actions: if $\pi \in \prod_i S_{X_i}$, then with $\rho^{\pi}(g)(x) = \pi^{-1} \rho(g)(\pi x)$, we see that $\rho^{\pi}$ is again a constrained action.
>
> **Find representatives of each $\prod_i S_{X_i}$ orbit of constrained actions.**

I can think of a number of approaches to this; so far they are either too dumb to work in the actual instances of this problem I care about, or too complicated for me to want to implement yet.

Does anyone know an off-the-shelf (e.g. implemented in an existing CAS) algorithm for this problem?

Comment: If for some reason it helps, I'm happy to restrict to the case that $G$ is abelian.

Comment: As an example of a problem instance where a naive algorithm takes a few minutes (too long!) to run, consider $G=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} = \{0,1,2,3\}$ and

$$
X = \{1\} \cup \{2, 3\} \cup \{4\} \cup \{5, 6, 7, 8\} \cup \{9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14\} \cup \{15, 16, 17, 
  18\} \cup \{19, 20, 21, 22\}
$$

Comment: \begin{align*}
Y_{1,\{1\}} & = \{4\} & Y_{1,\{4\}} & = \{1\} \\
Y_{2,\{1\}} & = \{1\} & Y_{2,\{4\}} & = \{4\} \\
Y_{3,\{1\}} & = \{4\} & Y_{3,\{4\}} & = \{1\} \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
Y_{g,\{2, 3\}} & = \{2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8\} \\
Y_{g,\{5, 6, 7, 8\}} & = \{2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8\} \\
Y_{g,\{9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14\}} & = \{9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14\} \\
Y_{g,\{15, 16, 17, 18\}} & = \{15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22\} \\
Y_{g,\{19, 20, 21, 22\}} & = \{15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22\}
\end{align*}

Comment: I've [moved some comments to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40956/discussion-on-question-by-scott-morrison-enumerating-group-actions-with-constrai), and improved the clarity of the question in response to those suggestions.